# Overlaying views & positioning

Tags: iphone

I have a tab bar view, and another UIView which contains a button, which needs to be visible just above the tab bar.

I have added another view which always sits above the current select tab's view, but can't figure out how to make it sit just above the tab bar [Screenshot http://img.skitch.com/20090524-jq6ufyiwp6c2uu1x5tkrrsd97m.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090524-jq6ufyiwp6c2uu1x5tkrrsd97m.jpg)

Comment: that looks like a tool i use called mockups @ http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups
it's actually really handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your view with button in the tab bar view and use either one of these

## – bringSubviewToFront:

## – insertSubview:aboveSubview:

to put it above all and check how many pixels you need to position your button so that it does not get above the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest sub-classing the tabbar to include the new view.  That way you do not have to worry about a tab overlaying the view.  All your resizing should be done automatically and you will never accidentally hide a component.

You can also have the controller also look after the button and view that you add.  you would just need to replace the tabbar in the tabbarviewcontroller to be your one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add it at the window level.